# Mockito Junit with a boolean returning method

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Version Info :

```
junit   : 5.2.0
Mockito : 2.23.4
```

I have the following method :

```
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService;

    public boolean getData(String Id, String version, String code) {
        RequestObj req = new RequestObj();
        req.setId(Id);
        req.setVersion(version);
        req.setCode(code);

        ResponseObj resp = someService.find(req);

        if(resp.getValue()){
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    
    }
}
```

Now I am writing a junit test case as below using Mockito :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyServiceImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    MyServiceImpl myServiceImpl;
    
    @Mock
    SomeService someService;

    @Test
    public void testGetData() {
        ResponseObj resp = new ResponseObj();
        resp.setValue(true);

        when(someService.find(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(resp);
        assertTrue(myServiceImpl.getData("01", "5.0", "abc"));
    }
}
```

I am getting errors like :

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnnecessaryStubbingException: 
Unnecessary stubbings detected in test class
```

When I am using the resp object then the error is no more :

```
@Test
public void testGetData() {
    ResponseObj resp = new ResponseObj();
    resp.setValue(true);

    Request req = new Request();
    req.setId(Id);
    req.setVersion(version);
    req.setCode(code);

    Mockito.when(someService.find(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(resp);
    assertEquals(resp, someService.find(req)); 
    assertTrue(myServiceImpl.getData("01", "5.0", "abc"));
}
```

I am new to mockito and junit. I know I am not able to write my test method properly. Please help to fix my test case.

Comment: Tested with mockito 3.3.3 and it works as expected. So please add your mockito version and the SomeService class to the question. The exception is raised if the method you mocked with when is not called at all. You can try to set the Mock to @Mock(lenient = true) (not recommended just for debugging). This disables such errors. However when it is really not called the assert should be false after the lenient change.

Comment: @mszalbach : Added the version info. I have updated the working scenario as well. Can u please check. It seems like if we do not use the stub it ignores the call. `@Mock(lenient = true)` is a solution and works. However do u see anything wrong in my test case ?

Comment: The test case is correct. The Problem is based on the Mockio Version or a conflict with some other Dependency like PowerMock or something I can not tell like a special compiler.
To find out more I would need an example project in maven or gradle to reproduce this error. If I just copy the code and create an example it works.